# Android-Load the database from list view quickly

Tags: database, dictionary

I have a sqlite database dictionary with about 300000 words. Can anybody help me to solve the problem loading the database from a listview as quickly as available?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a CursorAdapter. Create a class that extends CursorAdapter, like so:

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, flags);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // Change the id attribute to match your list item text view
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);  
        title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(yourColumnName)));
    }


    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Change the layout to your custom list item
        return inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
    }

}
```

Then, to set your list, you would write:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(yourQuery);
MyCursorAdapter adapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, cursor, 0);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```